# Make Wildcards for Target Extensions

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a target in my project which can have a large number of different extensions on it, and also a target without an extension:

```
target
target.a
target.b
...
target.x
```

I'd like to be able to specify the target using a wildcard for the extension, so I don't need to have a recipe for each target extension. I thought I might be able to do this through Pattern Rules as such:

```
target%: VAR=1
         $(MAKE) MY_VARS += $(VAR) $@
```

However this doesn't build the target when I run make. Can anyone suggest a way I might be able to do this wildcard?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have three problems.  First, you can't combine a target-specific variable in the same rule definition as a recipe.  Second, a pattern has to match at least one character, so the pattern `target%` doesn't match the target `target`.  Finally, when you provide variable assignments on a command line you can't use whitespace between the variable name, assignment operator, and value: they must all be the same word.

You could use this:

```
targe%: VAR=1
targe%:
        $(MAKE) MY_VARS+='$(VAR)' $@
```

Comment: You can also do `target target.%:` for the target as opposed to dropping the last character.

Comment: You can't write one rule that is both an implicit and explicit rule; you have to write two different rules.  There used to be a bug that this was allowed in some limited situations and not others, but that bug was fixed in GNU make 3.82.  Now GNU make will either fail outright or print a warning about deprecated syntax if you try to do this.

Comment: Interesting... I had tried it just before posting, but I'm running 3.81, so it didn't complain.   Why is this considered a bug?

Comment: Ok, just reading up on this.  Apparently the ability to mix implicit and explict rules has been reinstated in version 4.1, though there seems to be some debate on it.   In any case my suggestion would not be portable, and, while I think it looks nicer, it should be avoided.

Comment: It was an incorrect accident of implementation that never worked completely: for example you can't write `target.% target:` with the explicit target second not first, in any version of GNU make.  Also it only ever worked if you had no prerequisites or if your prerequisites were explicit (had no pattern).  Also, although the syntax is accepted again in 4.1 and above (because older Linux kernel makefiles use that syntax) it always prints a big fat warning that can't be disabled.

Comment: Thanks, this was a big help!